# Autofs doesn't mount shares on startup

Tags: opensuse, nfs, ldap, autofs

I am using OpenSuSE 12.1 with homes shared through LDAP and NFS. 
ldap stores the maps.
My problem is I can't have the shares mounted on boot. It's only working when restarting the autofs service manually.
On a CentOS 6.3 there is no such problem.

My `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd: files sss
group:  files sss

hosts:  files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files dns

services:       files
protocols:      files
rpc:            files
ethers:         files
netmasks:       files
netgroup:       files nis
publickey:      files

bootparams:     files
automount:      files ldap
aliases:        files
```

My `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`:

```
SIZELIMIT       20
TIMELIMIT       15
#DEREF          never
TLS_REQCERT     demand
uri     ldap://10.0.0.1
base    dc=domain,dc=com
```

My `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
reconnection_retries = 3
sbus_timeout = 30
services = nss, pam
domains = domain.com

[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root
reconnection_retries = 3

[pam]
reconnection_retries = 3

[domain/domain.com]
 id_provider = ldap
 auth_provider = ldap
 min_id = 500
 max_id = 30000
 ldap_schema = rfc2307
 ldap_uri =  ldaps://ldap-ms.local,  ldaps://ldap-sl.local, ldap://ldap
 ldap_search_base = dc=domain,dc=com
 ldap_user_search_base =  ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com
 ldap_group_search_base = ou=Group,dc=domain,dc=com
 ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/pki/CA/certs/domain-cacert.pem
 ldap_tls_reqcert = hard
 cache_credentials = true
 enumerate = True
```

My `/etc/sysconfig/autofs`:

```
MASTER_MAP_NAME="auto.master"
TIMEOUT=300
BROWSE_MODE="yes"
MAP_OBJECT_CLASS="automountMap"
ENTRY_OBJECT_CLASS="automount"
MAP_ATTRIBUTE="ou"
ENTRY_ATTRIBUTE="cn"
VALUE_ATTRIBUTE="automountInformation"
USE_MISC_DEVICE="yes"
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Any chance your LDAP service is not available with the maps in time for the booting file system query? That would explain the later success with restart once the system is up and stable.

Comment: What are the start-levels (within your target runlevel) for `autofs` and your ldap-client?

Comment: @zedman9991 This problem occurs only with my version of opensuse (12.1) On Centos 6.3 and OpenSuse 11.2 it works fine.

Comment: @Nils Autofs starts on runlevels 3 and 5.

Comment: There is a difference in the way autofs mounts maps on boot on opensuse 11.2 it mounts them at the access but on opensuse 12.1 it mounts them all but no access.

Comment: `ls /etc/init.d/rc3.d/S*autofs` - that is the start-level within runlevel 3. So what are the entries for your ldap-client-service and for autofs?

Comment: The commands return `/etc/init.d/rc3.d/S10autofs` `/etc/init.d/rc3.d/S10sssd`

Comment: Can U add some logs?

Comment: I have this same problem. To solve this on **some** machines, I created a script /etc/init.d/autofs_go `service autofs restart` and used update-rc.d to make it start on rc3.d and rc5.d using S99. But this doesn't seem to work on all machines.

Answer (score 1):

This question got bumped by community, and it's pretty old.
A lot of things has happened over the years, Michael mentioned one solution, using fstab. And the original problem was most likely do due execution-order at boot time. Network might not have been ready, some service might not have started etc.

There's also another solution if you're running systemd (which I doubt OP did at the time, but if you end up here through a search, and you do) here's another solution using systemd's automount feature.

```
[Unit]
Description=Network mapping
After=network.target

[Mount]
What=10.0.0.1:/share/stuff
Where=/mnt/remote_share
Type=nfs
Options=_netdev,auto

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The only drawback of this is that you have to be careful with what you name the service script. It's best described [here](https://cloudnull.io/2017/05/nfs-mount-via-systemd/), but a tl;dr-version is that the service-file must be named after the path it's going to mount. And all forward-slashes in said path has to be replaced with `-` in the service-file name for automatic mounting to work. The above example of `/mnt/remote_share would be a service-file called`mnt-remote_share.mount`

There's a bunch of [options](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) to go with this.
If systemd isn't your thing, there's also a lot of new stuff on the [autofs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs) side which does a pretty good job *(all be it a bit complicated for my taste)*.

If you want to use a fstab entry instead but utilize systemd's auto-hook feature, here's what your fstab could look like:

```
10.0.0.1:/share/stuff   /mnt/remote_share  nfs  noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,timeo=14,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min 0 0
```

And if neither of those work, there's also the pure-fstab solution:

```
10.0.0.1:/share/stuff   /mnt/remote_share   nfs   defaults,soft,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,timeo=900,retrans=5,_netdev 0 0
```

I'll drop a few links to good documentation on the subject (bare in mind, it's a different OS. But their Wiki is as of writing this one of the best on the market):

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS#Mount_using_/etc/fstab_with_systemd
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autofs
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs#NFS_network_mounts

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the mount locations to your fstab.

You could also use sshfs. 
Configure ssh to use public key authentication.

On the server:

sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Change to or add ServerKeyBits 2048 to /etc/ssh/sshd_config

On the Client

ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048

ssh-copy-id from the client computer to the server.
Use your password for your user on the server machine to login

Change /etc/ssh/sshd_config: PasswordAuthentication no, UsePAM no

I use other settings as well to harden ssh but for this example it is not needed.

If your outside your lan setup a dyndns or noip updater, and setup portforwarding on your router so port 23 or what ever port you decide to use to obfuscate the service is forwarded to the server ip address, if you need help with that just ask.

Then:

sshfs USER@SERVERADDRESS:/mnt/DRIVELOCATION /PATH/TO/MOUNT/DRIVE/TO

I set this command as a launcher on the main menu for some drives and for others in the fstab.

I know it works because I use this same setup plus the hardening everyday.

This way you can get rid of the need for autofs and its required overhead.